# When calculating the specific heat capacity of a solution, would the specific heat capacity of the copper calorimeter used affect the final results?

Tags: thermodynamics

I experimentally calculated the specific heat capacities of solutions by heating them in a copper calorimeter- will I need to take the specific heat capacity of copper into account during my calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because a copper calorimeter might have a significant thermal capacity ie heat is required to raise its temperature.

More recently materials like polystyrene are used for the containing vessel as polystyrene has a low specific heat capacity and also is a comparatively good insulator.